# I ran this script in my react native development server and now it wont work

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, expo

```
rm -rf ios/build/; kill $(lsof -t -i:8081); react-native run-ios
```

I'm not sure what that did but i have a feeling that thats what did the damage
error Could not connect to development server

also getting no bundle url present as an error

```
    jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision: functions
  The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
    * <rootDir>/functions/package.json
    * <rootDir>/src/config/functions/package.json

ERROR
23:06
Failed to construct transformer:  DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
    at setModule (/Users/arichayo/Documents/mitzvahCenterIos/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:620:17)
    at workerReply (/Users/arichayo/Documents/mitzvahCenterIos/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:691:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 177) {
  mockPath1: 'functions/package.json',
  mockPath2: 'src/config/functions/package.json'
}
ERROR
23:06
(node:642) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
    at setModule (/Users/arichayo/Documents/mitzvahCenterIos/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:620:17)
    at workerReply (/Users/arichayo/Documents/mitzvahCenterIos/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:691:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 177)
(node:642) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:642) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

i got this error in expo chrome cli
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: That the node server is not working

Comment: I think it's killing the 8081 which is usually where the server runs through or something like that

Comment: have you tried restarting your computer / node just to make sure that everything is up?

Comment: I'll try that right now I just don't think that's what it is

Comment: restarting didnt work

Comment: This post has the same error message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852276/amplify-react-native-duplicate-error-using-amplify-add-api