# Amplify: Expo Could not connect to development server

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I have a React-Native app, using AWS Amplify that works with Expo when testing  using `expo start --web`, but I am trying to test on my iOS device and get a `Could not connect to development server.` Error. `URL: http://192.168.1.6:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false`

EDIT: I have tried starting a blank project, using `amplify pull`, and then this error occurs:

```
jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision: projectamplifyjsc7fc9745PostConfirmation
  The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
    * <rootDir>\amplify\#current-cloud-backend\function\projectamplifyjsc7fc9745PostConfirmation\src\package.json
    * <rootDir>\amplify\backend\function\projectamplifyjsc7fc9745PostConfirmation\src\package.json    

Failed to construct transformer:  DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
    at setModule (C:\Users\me\Desktop\project\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:620:17)
    at workerReply (C:\Users\me\Desktop\project\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:691:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 50) {
  mockPath1: 'amplify\\#current-cloud-backend\\function\\projectamplifyjsc7fc9745PostConfirmation\\src\\package.json',
  mockPath2: 'amplify\\backend\\function\\projectamplifyjsc7fc9745PostConfirmation\\src\\package.json'}
Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
    at setModule (C:\Users\me\Desktop\project\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:620:17)
    at workerReply (C:\Users\me\Desktop\project\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:691:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 50)
Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
    at setModule (C:\Users\me\Desktop\project\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:620:17)
    at workerReply (C:\Users\me\Desktop\project\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:691:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 50)
```

What is this and how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer comes from someone who had a similar issue with the Amplify API, find it here: [Amplify React Native - Duplicate Error using amplify add api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852276/amplify-react-native-duplicate-error-using-amplify-add-api)

Solution is simple (at least for me, guess it could depend on what amplify services you use).

> Amplify creates a copy of your current cloud backend configuration in
> `amplify/#current-cloud-backend/`.
>
> You don't need those files to build your app, so you can ignore them
> in order to get rid of the error.
>
> To do so, you can create a blacklist and add the folder to it. Create
> a `rn-cli.config.js` file in the root of your project.
>
> `./rn-cli.config.js`:
>
> ````
> require('metro').createBlacklist;
>
> const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');
>
> module.exports = {   resolver: {
>     blacklistRE: blacklist([/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/]),   }, }; ```
> ````

See answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60899723/11255886