# Where is the AWS Amplify documentation for TypeScript and Expo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, expo, aws-amplify

Following [the simple steps](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js/) outlined in the AWS documentation, starting with a working Expo app (using DataStore), to add Authentication with

```bash
amplify add auth
amplify push
```

and the basic boilerplate of

```js
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native'
```

I get a "variety pack" of errors suddenly:

1. In my IDE the import is flagged with

   ```
   S7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'aws-amplify-react-native'.
   ```
2. Bundling as part of `expo start --dev-client` fails with

   ```
   Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
   jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision: learning600433b2PostConfirmation
     The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
       * <rootDir>/amplify/#current-cloud-backend/function/learning600433b2PostConfirmation/src/package.json
       * <rootDir>/amplify/backend/function/learning600433b2PostConfirmation/src/package.json

   Failed to construct transformer:  DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
   ...
   Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
   ...
   ⠋ Stopping ...
   RuntimeError: abort(Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
   ```
3. And once that's fixed (see below) I every time I run with `expo start --dev-client` I get:

   ```
   [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: No credentials, applicationId or region]
   at node_modules/@aws-amplify/analytics/lib-esm/Providers/AWSPinpointProvider.js:176:66 in __generator$argument_1
   at node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-pinpoint/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:144:21 in step
   at node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-pinpoint/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:125:60 in <anonymous>
   at node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-pinpoint/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:115:51 in fulfilled
   ```

I can fix

1. by ignoring the warning,
2. [by adding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60923649/656912)

   ```js
   resolver: { blacklistRE: /#current-cloud-backend\/.*/ }
   ```

   to the `module.exports` in `metro.config.js`, and
3. [by adding](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/5918#issuecomment-871060333)

   ```js
   Analytics: { disabled: true }
   ```

   to the configuration I supply to `Amplify.configure` when I start my app.

My question is: How was I supposed to know all this? Where is it documented? What other undocumented (and time consuming) surprises lurk in the murky swamps of AWS Amplify —

OK, that's more of a rant than a question, sorry.

My question is: Where is the documentation for using AWS Amplify with Expo? Is there a single document I'm missing that describes these (and other) required steps?

Comment: Are you using TS or JS?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary TS

Comment: Error 1&2 is related to you using TS as opposed to JS which is what the docs target: `https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js`

Comment: Error 3 seems to be one of those rogue errors that many people have (& shouldn't ofc). To be completely honest with you, Amplify seems to be one of the areas where AWS has lacked in - both doc wise & implementation wise. I advise anyone starting a new project to not use Amplify & instead do the glue logic themselves to save time in the long run. You'll find more things on the way... it's just one of the weakpoints currently IMHO & I'm saying that as someone who is all in on AWS.

Comment: The docs are just poor, is the answer - you're right. However, they are open source so while I don't have a good answer, you can try to be the change you want to see! https://github.com/aws-amplify/docs

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yeah sadly I'm starting to feel the same way. Amplify is just not worth it. I can clearly see the potential, and why people are drawn in; but the docs are just SO bad that it will be catastrophic in the longer run. Already I have very little confidence in my code.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary And there's stuff like this: "New Version Available
The documentation on this page refers to styling version 1 of the Authenticator.
For styling the updated version, please see this documentation", that links to docs that don't work _at all_ for a mobile app. So there not really "new" at all, just _incompatible_ (which I suppose is a kind of "new").

Comment: I understand, it’s a real shame. Use Terraform/CDK for your infra & glue it yourself